# Wrong name display on navigation menu - Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I am very confused with this. Why is that in Navigation Menu, a wrong name was displayed like on the image below.

The person's name is Jacob but it displays Rod.

Can someone help? Thanks!

[wrong name display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD3ey.png)

Comment: Check the alias for the provided ID. Also show us the property/value being set on the Name field.

Comment: If you're reading from a datasource (for example, a Users table) remember that filters will stay applied until they are removed. Are you filtering for Rod at some point on the same datasource?